# UIActivityViewController Not Displaying Expected AirDrop Option for Custom File Type in My App

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

So the typical way you share a document via `UIActivityViewController` is code similar to this:

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [obj], applicationActivities: nil)
ac.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The issue is I'm not sure what kind of class `obj` is supposed to be. I have a file that works with the eDrawings iOS app from SolidWorks. I know that it works because I was able to AirDrop it from my laptop and it got copied over and opened correctly on my iPad that has the eDrawings app on it.

If you take a look in a mail message that contains the eDrawings supported file types on said iPad, you can see that it provides the expected option in the popover.

[image]

My question is, how can I do the same thing? Mail must be doing it generically without knowing the UTI explicitly, so what should my `obj` field be in the example code I provided above in order to get my activity view controller to display the same option as in Mail? I've tried using an `NSURL` both with the file downloaded locally as well as a URL on the web. Neither of those work. I would think I should just use an `NSData`, but at that point, how would the activity view controller know what type it is implicitly like it does in Mail?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of "Activity View" as the place in iOS (a file-free environment) where developers can allow their files to escape the device.

The API says give me a list and I'll fill the view. The docs have the details, hidden in the enum descriptions...

*for AirDrop*

> When using this service, you can provide NSString, NSAttributedString, UIImage, ALAsset, and NSURL objects as data for the activity items. You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the assets-library scheme. You may also provide NSArray or NSDictionary objects that contain the listed data types.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype/1620665-airdrop

*for Mail*

> When using this service, you can provide NSString and UIImage objects and NSURL objects pointing to local files as data for the activity items.
>   To specify an NSData object, you must implement the UIActivityItemSource protocol, return the data object in activityViewController(*:itemForActivityType:), and return the data object’s UTI in activityViewController(*:dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:). Also, you may need to register the appropriate mapping so that the MIME type can be determined.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype/1620669-mail

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityitemsource?language=objc) in your obj class.